# The Bra-Ket Notation in LaTeX

Tags: packages, braket

I want to write the following symbol in LaTeX:

[image]

I'm using the following (minimal) code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{braket}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \ket \psi{(t)}
    \end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

I don't however get the desired result. The $t$ symbol appears outside the ket, as opposed to the output in the figure. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you've placed the `(t)` outside the scope of the `\ket` command.

just move the open brace before the `\psi`:

```
\ket {\psi(t)}.
```

off-topic: since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically, it's not necessary
to specify them both.

Comment: Awesome. Btw, if you can, please do introduce a tag for "Braket" over here. I think that'd be helpful.

Comment: @JunaidAftab Well I actually just created the tag by accident, but I didn't mean to! Tags are about indexing similar questions, they're a filing system essentially. As it says on the privileges page "You should always favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site." Tags aren't about providing a list of contents for your post. They should be broad. And braket notation simply isn't a LaTeX topic. Anyway, welcome to the site and +1 barbara

Comment: @Au101 -- at first i entered this as a comment, thinking there would be a previous question that had an appropriate answer. but nothing suitable came up.  however, there *are* numerous questions about this package (as well as a lot of misspellings of regular brackets).  so i'd favor a dedicated tag for the package, and would help "clean up" prior questions and "misdeeds".

Comment: Oh, fair enough :) well now we have one :P I had also overlooked the `braket` package. Sorry for the mess, but I think we got there in the end :)