# iopart class is not friend with physics package

Tags: packages, physics

I am using iopart class for my document. In an equation I wish to use `ket`. For this reason I use `\usepackage{physics}`. But when I type this package, I alarmed by `Command \equation already defined.` And proram does not compile!!!

How I write the symbol `ket`?

Comment: `physics` is not a package too many are excited about. For `\ket` you can load the `braket` package.

Comment: `iopart` is not friend to *many* packages, including `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg: in French, there is this article (and a workaround) about incompatibilities between `iopart` and `asmmath` (the guilty is `iopart`): http://science.thilucmic.fr/index.php?c=la&p=iopart-amsmath. The translation in English provided by for example Google seems good.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested byquark67 we can use amsmath workaround by Thierry Masson on this occasion.

Note whilst IOPscience suggest not using amsmath because of the equation clash they do not exclude you using amsmath with other classes such as standard article.

> ["*...using the IOP class file may help to speed the publication of
>   accepted articles. Note that there is an incompatibility between
>   amsmath.sty and iopart.cls.* **If your article relies on commands in
>   amsmath.sty that are not available in iopart.cls, you may wish to
>   consider using a different class file...**"](https://publishingsupport.iopscience.iop.org/questions/latex-template/)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart} % Avoid iopams

% From http://science.thilucmic.fr/index.php?c=la&p=iopart-amsmath&l=en
% Blocks out ! LaTeX Error: Command \equation* already defined when loading amsmath
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname=\relax 
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname=\relax 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} % note amssymb will load amsfonts per Barbara Beeton also to avoid physics use
\usepackage{braket} % as suggested by marmot and this example answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316836/the-bra-ket-notation-in-latex
    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \ket {\psi(t)}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```